# Stylesheet for tooltip in firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, stylesheet

I've developed a Firefox extension for displaying explanations for some unusual words. My problem is that my tooltip get's modified by other stylesheets of the current page. So on some pages my stylesheet looks fine and on some it's totally messed up. Is there a way to limit my stylesheet to my tooltip notes so that stylesheets from the webpage wouldn't affect mine?

I'm loading my stylesheet that way:

```js
initTooltipStyle: function(on) {
        var sss = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);

        var uri = makeURI("resource://tooltip/tooltip.css");
        if (sss.sheetRegistered(uri, sss.USER_SHEET))
            sss.unregisterSheet(uri, sss.USER_SHEET);
        if (on)
            sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.USER_SHEET);
},
```

Comment: Are you using `!important` in your styles?

Comment: I'm using !important in every style but still getting conflicts

Comment: Debugging it in detail it looks like the problem are not assigned options. Would there be another solution aside from adding all possible options to my stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem. Most of the time the style property which you didn't applied to your element will be easily overriden by webpages. For instance, if you didn't declare margin for your div element and webpage has declared `div{margin:0;}` your element will also inherit it. Try adding reset.css to your elemets(http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Then try adding your elements into the root elemnt of the page instead of body. `document.documentElement.appendChild()`. These techniques helped me.

Hope that helps!